how can get radio values to api with formik?
I want to get radio values and pass them to API with Formik.
you can see code below:
<Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
  <FormControl>
    <FormLabel>نوع سرویس:</FormLabel>
    <RadioGroup row>
      <FormControlLabel
        value={ServiceTypeEnum.Went}
        name="ServiceType"
        control={<Radio />}
        label="رفت"
      />
      <FormControlLabel
        value={ServiceTypeEnum.Return}
        control={<Radio />}
        label="برگشت"
        name="ServiceType"
      />
      <FormControlLabel
        value={ServiceTypeEnum.WentReturn}
        control={<Radio />}
        name="ServiceType"
        label="رفت و برگشت"
      />
    </RadioGroup>
  </FormControl>
</Grid>

do you prefer to use enum for this solution?

What types of questions should I avoid asking?

Stack Overflow is a community where we help each other by providing clear, detailed questions and answers. Improving the quality of your question can increase the chances of getting helpful responses and also help others who might have a similar issue in the future.

im reading radio component n mui and find below code:
 <FormLabel>نوع سرویس:</FormLabel>
                                    <RadioGroup row
                                        onChange={handleChange}

                                        defaultValue={ServiceTypeEnum.Return}
                                        name="ServiceType"
                                    >
                                        <FormControlLabel
                                            control={<Radio />}
                                            label="رفت"
                                            value={ServiceTypeEnum.Went}
                                        />
                                        <FormControlLabel
                                            control={<Radio />}
                                            label="برگشت"
                                            value={ServiceTypeEnum.Return}
                                        />
                                        <FormControlLabel
                                            control={<Radio />}
                                            label="رفت و برگشت"
                                            value={ServiceTypeEnum.WentReturn}
                                        />
                                    </RadioGroup>

